# How to manage cookie on mobile browser?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cookies

How can i edit my cookies in chrome on my iOS/android device?

Answer (score 1):

For those who's still looking for an answer here is an instruction for an iPhone:

> You can't see cookie data on the phone itself, but if you activate
>   Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector you can connect the
>   iPhone to an Apple computer with a cable and open Safari. Activate the
>   Develop menu in Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar
>
> Now you can open a page on the iPhone and then select Develop >
>   your_phone > the_page on the computer to see an inspector for the page
>   on the phone. The second icon at the top is for storage and will show
>   cookies for the page you show on the phone.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/75186

Answer (score 1):

** Edit 2023-08-28 **

The extension Cookie-Editor is available on the App store for iOS.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cookie-editor/id6446215341

** Edit 2023-03-13 **

Firefox now only allows a very narrow set of extensions to run on Android. Until this is updated, this is not an option anymore. I'm in the process of making it available on Safari for iOS soon.

---

If you are still looking, I made a Firefox extension called Cookie-Editor that also works on Android phones. It is similar to EditThisCookie.

It lets you create, edit and delete your cookies as well as importing or exporting them.

You can find it here: https://cookie-editor.cgagnier.ca or directly on the firefox store here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-editor/

Comment: The cookieeditor works on firefox on android. But, is there a way to persist the value of the cookie? Everytime i close the firefox and launch the target website i see that the cookie value is set back to it's default. I would like to save the cookie value to something and would like to see this value everytime i load the website. Is this possible? Whatever i save, it looks like the value is saved until i close and reopen the firefox.

Comment: The extension can't be installed on the latest firefox for android

Answer (score 0):

please clarify your question. This seems very broard.

However,

"This article applies to Chrome for Mobile.

Adjust the type of content that websites can show and the information that they can use to enhance your web experience.

Touch Chrome menu > Settings.
Touch (Advanced) Content settings.
The information below applies to all mobile devices

Block pop-ups. Prevent websites from showing additional windows automatically.
Accept cookies. Websites can store small files on your device in order to save your preferences on websites or keep you signed in. Deselect to prevent webpages from storing cookies on your mobile device.
The information below applies to Chrome for Android only.

Enable JavaScript. Many web developers use JavaScript to make their websites more interactive. Sites may function correctly only if they can run JavaScript on your mobile device.
Voice and Video calling. Allow sites with media functionality, such as video conferencing, to request access to your camera and microphone.
Google Translate. Translate pages written in other languages.
Google location settings. Allow sites with location-specific content to ask whether you want to share your location using your mobile device’s location information.
Website settings. If you want to clear location permissions or local data stored on your device for a specific site, touch this option."

Comment: I'm looking for something like this - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en - but for mobile browser.

Comment: @Skay if you are still looking for something like editthiscookie but for mobile, you should look at my answer to this question